# Auto fill other column in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have column in mysql table like this:

```
| Column A | Column B |
| A        |          | 
| B        |          |
| C        |          |
| D        |          | 
| E        |          |
```

I want to auto fill the other column using rule if A,C,D then fill X and if B, E fill the Y in the column B field.

The result will be like this:

```
| Column A | Column B |
|----------|----------|
| A        | X        |
| B        | Y        |
| C        | X        |
| D        | X        | 
| E        | Y        |
```

Is there are an easy way to do that in MySQL query?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Is this a one-time backfill or something you want to happen on every operation on the table (INSERT/UPDATE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET B = CASE
  WHEN A IN ('A','C','D') THEN 'X' 
  WHEN A IN ('B','E') THEN 'Y'
END
```

Comment: You have an extra `CASE` in your answer. Each option is marked only by the `WHEN` keyword (inside the `CASE` ... `END` block).

Comment: Nice catch. The dangers of copy/paste.